# fake linux file with file io hooks

Tags: linux, file, module, kernel, hook

I want to create a file that applications can open, but the file does not exist but is instead delivered by another userspace application hooking read and write.  Is there a way to do this without creating a kernel module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) ([Filesystem in Userspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)). Indeed, it requires using some *existing* kernel module (for `fuse` filesystems), but the bulk of the code (and all the code *you* need to write) is in user-space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipe (named or anonymous).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29#Creating_pipelines_programmatically

Comment: I need a solution which supports seeking

Comment: In this case you can use tmpfs - kind of a virtual partition kept in memory. "Everything stored in tmpfs is temporary in the sense that no files will be created on the hard drive; however, swap space is used as backing store in case of low memory situations. On reboot, everything in tmpfs will be lost." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs#Linux

Comment: Then FUSE is the answer, see my answer below.